# mod_rewrite does not return $_GET-value?

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

I have a problem with mod-rewrite, to be more precise, it doesn't redirect me properly. Everything works fine on my local server, the problem only occurs when the site goes live... This is what I have in the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(tutorial|news|out|profile|script)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(tutorial|news)/([0-9]+)/post-comment/?$ $1.php?id=$2&action=postcmt [L]

RewriteRule ^atelier/([0-9]+)/?$ img/gallery/view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^get/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1/get.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^get/brushes/(abr|img)/([0-9]+)/?$ brushes/$1.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(c|series|type)/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3&page=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(c|series|type)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^design/preview/([0-9]+)/?$ design/preview.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/send/?$ $1.php?action=send [L]
RewriteRule ^askme/post-question/?$ ask.php?action=ask [L]
```

If I enter news/5/ for example, it will only redirect me to news.php, design/preview/5 will only take me to design/preview.php and so forth. On the contrary, get/brushes/abr/1 works fine... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Apache are you using for development and production?

( Not a solution ) but I think you should prepend the start of the urls with a leading '/', eg ^/?design/preview and /design-preview.php?id=$1 ( though please test locally if possible ).

Comment: I'm using 2.2.11 on my local server and 2.0 online. I tried what you suggested, no difference... :(

Comment: Yes, they're both Windows servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) could cause this behavior. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to start from the simplest place and add complication after, does this work for you?

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like the rewrite engine is even switched on then - although I can see you have the "RewriteEngine on" in your .htaccess